# Dockerfile volume: local changes are not reflected in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am using docker-compose to create a multi-container environment where I have one mongodb instance and two python applications. I am having trouble when I am changing my files locally, but  `docker-compose up` doesn't reflect the changes I made in my file. What am I doing wrong?

My project structure:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── form
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
│       ├── form_action.html
│       └── form_sumbit.html
├── notify
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── requirements.txt
└── README
```

Dockerfiles are pretty similar for two apps. One is given below:

```
FROM python:2.7
ADD . /notify
WORKDIR /notify
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mongo:3.0.2
    container_name: mongo
    networks:
      db_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.1.1


  web:
    build: form
    command: python -u app.py
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - form:/form
    environment:
      MONGODB_HOST: 172.16.1.1
    networks:
      db_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.1.2

  notification:
    build: notify
    command: python -u app.py
    volumes:
      - notify:/notify
    environment:
      MONGODB_HOST: 172.16.1.1
    networks:
      db_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.1.3

networks:
  db_net:
    external: true

volumes:
  form:   
  notify:
```

Here is my output for `docker volume ps`:

```
local               form
local               healthcarereminder_form
local               healthcarereminder_notify
local               notify
```

[My understanding till now: You can see there are two instances of form and notify, with one having project folder name appended. So docker might be looking for changes in a different file. I am not sure.]

Comment: What do you mean by, “I am changing my files locally”? What file are you changing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to mount a host directory in the docker-compose file do not declare `notify` as a VOLUME directive.

Instead treat it like a local folder

```
notification:
    build: notify
    command: python -u app.py
    volumes:
      # this points to a relative ./notify directory.
      - ./notify:/notify
    environment:
....

volumes:
  form:   
  #do not declare the volume here.
  # notify:
```

When you were declare a VOLUME node at the bottom of the docker-compose file, docker makes an special internal directory meant to be shared between docker images. Here is more details: https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#add-a-data-volume